# How to verify permissions on all SQL accounts along request sequence of ASPX page

Tags: sql, ajax, authentication, asp.net

I have a previously working ASPX website which also supports AJAX.  However, we just upgraded our SQL Server from 2008 Evaluation to 2008 R2 version 10.50.16 and now this website is no longer working.
I believe the problem is that now we need to again restore original SQL accounts and settings prior to this upgrade.  This website also uses AJAX.  Which accounts need to be created to fix this problem?  When I navigate to this URL, I get the message below:

> The address is not valid.

Comment: How was SQL Server upgraded - was the data backed up & restored to a brand new instance?  What version was the old one, and the new one?  The account(s) you're interested in are the ones used in the connection string...

Comment: Thanks.  I updated the version info above.  Yes, all of the tables were backed up and restored.  But the Logins were not.  How/where would I check the connection string?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, logins aren't part of the backup/restore process - you need to recreate them (assuming they don't already exist) and then sync the 2008R2 users with the user references in the backup - MSDN is down ATM, but you want to use `ALTER USER` syntax to do this (`sp_change_users_login` is likely deprecated). http://blog.gre-sqlserver-solutions.com/2010/03/spchangeuserslogin-and-sql-server-2008.html

Sorry, I don't know where in ASPX or the AJAX to find a connection string - look for anything that referenced the old server - a hostname or IP, the catalog/database name, the default port is 1433...